# div-width depends on width of sibling

Tags: html, css

Following is a menu that I am trying to create.

I want menu item divs to be independent in width, and have a width only as much is required for the text inside which i thought was default behavior. Where did I go wrong?

```css
.patleLast {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 1000px 0px 1000px 1000px;
  background-color: black;
  width: auto;
  margin: 1px;
}

.patleFirst {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 1000px 1000px 0px 1000px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 1px;
}

.patle {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 1000px 0px 0px 1000px;
  background-color: black;
}

.topPan {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 0px;
  color:white;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  z-index: 1000;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="topPan">
  <div class="patleFirst">
    Book Tickets
  </div>
  <div class="patle">
    Screening Schedule
  </div>
  <div class="patleLast">
    Book Tickets
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `auto` width of a div is 100%..the only restriction here is the positioning of the parent which collapses to the width of the largest child....so they are all the width of the largest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. The default `display` for `div`s is `block` which will always take up the full width.

To achieve the behaviour you are after make the following changes to CSS:

- Add `float: right;` to `.patleLast, .patleFirst, .patle` - this will shrink the `div`s to fit its content
- Add `clear: both;` to `.patleLast, .patleFirst, .patle` - this will ensure they wrap onto new lines

By floating the `div` the width is computed as "shrink to fit".

> If 'width' is computed as 'auto', the used value is the "shrink-to-fit" width.

Floating, non-replaced elements (https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#float-width)

```css
.patleLast {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 1000px 0px 1000px 1000px;
  background-color: black;
  width: auto;
  margin: 1px;
}

.patleFirst {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 1000px 1000px 0px 1000px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 1px;
}

.patle {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 1000px 0px 0px 1000px;
  background-color: black;
}

.patleLast, .patleFirst , .patle {
  clear: both;
  float: right;
}

.topPan {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 0px;
  color:white;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  z-index: 1000;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="topPan">
  <div class="patleFirst">
    Book Tickets
  </div>
  <div class="patle">
    Screening Schedule
  </div>
  <div class="patleLast">
    Book Tickets
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the proper behavior for block elements.
Besides that semantically more proper would be to use list element

https://jsfiddle.net/bkv9rzr2/

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">item one</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">item three</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
</ul>

ul {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 0px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  z-index: 1000;
  text-align: right;
}

a {
    color:white;
}

ul li {
  display:block;
  margin:1px;
}

ul li a {
  display:inline-block;
  background:#000;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
  transition:.2s;
}

ul li:first-child a {
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
}

ul li:last-child a {
  border-radius: 20px 0px 20px 20px;
}

ul li a:hover {
  padding:10px 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not typical div behavior. By default `<div>` elements have `display: block`, which will try to stretch them to the full width of the container. You're going to want to use `display: inline-block` or `float: left`. Both of these will make the divs take the size of their content, however they will also try to line the elements side by side, instead of make them fall under each other.

One workaround for this is to insert `<br/>` tags after each element. Or add `:after` pseudo-selectors which have `display: block`.